# Should I have a seperate database to store financial data for each user in my postgreSQL server?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

I am creating accounting/invoicing software and my database is in postgreSQL. Should I create a separate database for each user since the data is sensitive financial data? Or is having a user foreign key secure enough? If I am hosting the database on aws I understand that I could have a few db servers across multiple availability zones and regions so that if one is compromised it wouldn't effect everyone even if many users have info stored in a single database. Is this safe enough? Thanks!

Comment: This is fairly opinion based. My take is that if, by design, you have to create a new database object every time a new customer comes on board, then your design is going to cause lots of pain. Your SQL is going to get ugly if you, internally, need to combine customer data. Your security is going to be not-amazing (your application will have to have credentials with enough permissions to create objects... yuck). I would personally avoid this.

Comment: Not to mention its highly expensive and a waste of memory - there'd be no way in a lifetime of transactions that you'd ever get remotely close of using enough data for 1 user to justify having a db per user. Encrypt your data. Funny enough, I am actually researching that right now. Public and Private keys vs something that hashes and salts.

Comment: Why? Not even a bank or any other financial institution is doing that. Could you image a bank with 10 million customers and 10 million databases to maintain...

Comment: Thanks I have little experience so I don't know what industry practice is. It makes more sense now to maintain one database and utilize encryption. Doesn't this bring about a single point of failure tho?

Comment: It's always a question of trade-offs. If you were absolutely paranoid, you could have the PII of each user encrypted by their password. However, if you went down that route, if they ever lose their password, you're going to lose all of their information. But in general you are right, it is a single point of failure so things like key management is absolutely critical.

Answer (score 3):

In general no. Encrypt the data so that if someone exfiltrates a dump they can't actually use it without the decryption key. If you're worried that someone with admin access can see the user's information then you might want to consider a user-level encryption for all fields related to personally identifiable information.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways you could go about it but I wouldn’t create a new DB for every customers. It will be too expensive and a pain to maintain and evolve.

To me, this sounds like you are creating a multi-tenant application.

I’d personally use the row-level security feature in Postgres ([see this article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/multi-tenant-data-isolation-with-postgresql-row-level-security/)) or create a separate Schema for each Customer.

You can add an extra layer of protection with encryption at rest. AWS support it ([link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.Encryption.html))